# How can I use libraries in external js files?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to write my objects in a separate js file to make my main HTML file easier to organise. When I use jquery or oCanvas (canvas library) syntax, it doesn't seem to recognise it and fails to execute. I want to be able to make object templates for my main to make clones from (using the *clone()* function in oCanvas).

**Main HTML**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = oCanvas.create({
        canvas: "#myCanvas",
        background: "#CCCCCC"
    });
    helloworld();

</script>
```

**External JS File**

```
var rectangle = canvas.display.rectangle({
    x: 77,
    y: 77,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    fill: "#0aa"
});

function helloworld(){
    alert(rectangle.x);
};
```

When I call for the object `rectangle` and alert it's x property it fails. Is this something to do with making the object global?

Comment: You closed over helloworld, and as a result cannot access it.

Comment: What do you mean by closed over?

Comment: you can trigger events for your libraries, and listen it.

Comment: It hasn't been closed over. That's a more complicated pattern then this uses. It's just scoped. (If `helloworld` was exposed outside the ready event handler function, then `rectangle` would be closed over).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: @Quentin - Sure it has. You even reference the closure yourself. jQuery's ready callback function's scope is a closure. And its variables (including the helloworld function) are closed-over with that scope. As a result they cannot be accessed outside of the closure unless exposed.

Comment: Ah, actually, I see why you said that and where the confusion came from. When I posted my comment at first the post wrapped the "external js" inside of `$(function(){ /*extneral code*/ }`. After my comment the ready shortcut was removed and that is where the confusion was. So, you are correct that it wasn't closed over when you viewed it. But when I viewed it, it was.

Comment: Hey, why are you fix your question? How can other people reuse it, when you'll solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});` since:

- By defining it inside another function, `helloworld` is not a global so you can't reach it from your other script element *and*
- `rectangle` won't be given a value until the DOM ready event has fired (which will be after your attempt to call `helloworld`.

---

*After the edit to the question*

This is your order of code execution:

1. Call a function on the canvas and assign the value to `rectangle`
2. Create the canvas
3. Call `helloworld` which tries to read a value from `rectangle`

You have to create the canvas before you try to read data from it.

Comment: Yeah I realised why that didn't work now. I have made edits to my question

Comment: The only way I can think of doing that is to create the canvas in the js file which works. Is there a way in which I keep the canvas object in the main HTML?

Comment: Use a function, pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Because `helloworld` is in a closure, you'll need to export it to an outer scope to use it somewhere else:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var rectangle = canvas.display.rectangle({
    x: 77,
    y: 77,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    fill: "#0aa"
});

function helloworld(){
    alert(rectangle.x);
};

window.helloworld = helloworld; // make it global

});
```

However, the script you pasted calls the function immediately, and it won't be defined until after this runs. So you'd have to wait until the DOM is loaded before calling `helloworld()`.

Comment: That won't work. The attempt to call it comes before the ready event fires.

Answer (score 0):

One of ways:

You should trigger your custom events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  window.hello = function(name){alert('Hello, '+name+'!');}
  // document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('libLoaded', { name: 'hello' }));
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('libLoaded_hello', {}));
  ...
});
```

And wait it:

```
document.addEventListener('libLoaded_hello', function(e){
  // console.log(e.name);
  hello('World');
});
```